# IRequiresSessionState vs IReadOnlySessionState

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state, httphandler

What is the difference between `IRequiresSessionState` and `IReadOnlySessionState` beside the inability of the second to save changes to the session variables?

Both provide me the ability to access session variables in my `HttpHandler`. But why would I prefer `IReadOnlySessionState`? It just restricts me from saving the session for the next request.
Or does it gives me an performance advantage over `IRequiresSessionState`?

When would I prefer to use `IReadOnlySessionState` over `IRequiresSessionState`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One critical difference is that IRequiresSessionState puts an exclusive lock on the current session, thereby potentially limiting the # of concurrent requests from the current user. (For more background on this locking phenomenon, see [Is it possible to force request concurrency when using ASP.NET sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702602/is-it-possible-to-force-request-concurrency-when-using-asp-net-sessions))

In contrast, IReadOnlySessionState does not acquire an exclusive lock.

This is the same thing documented in [renad's helpful answer to an almost identical SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10139034).

The best official documentation I've found for this is from MSDN article [Session State Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx):

> Three of the most important methods in a session state provider are GetItem, GetItemExclusive, and SetAndReleaseItemExclusive. The first two are called by SessionStateModule to retrieve a session from the data source. If the requested page implements the IRequiresSessionState interface (by default, all pages implement IRequiresSessionState), SessionStateModule's AcquireRequestState event handler calls the session state provider's GetItemExclusive method. The word "Exclusive" in the method name means that the session should be retrieved only if it's not currently being used by another request. If, on the other hand, the requested page implements the IReadOnlySessionState interface (the most common way to achieve this is to include an EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" attribute in the page's @ Page directive), SessionStateModule calls the provider's GetItem method. No exclusivity is required here, because overlapping read accesses are permitted by SessionStateModule.

Note the parallel between explicitly using these interfaces and using the [EnableSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enablesessionstate.aspx) Page directive:

- EnableSessionState=False <-> no I*SessionState interface
- EnableSessionState=True <-> IRequiresSessionState interface
- EnableSessionState=ReadOnly <-> IReadOnlySessionState

Comment: +1 for locking - **extremely** important if a web application may process a handful of async requests at the same time which use Session state.

Answer (score 7):

That interface controls whether the framework will save the current session state at the end of the request.  It makes a bigger difference when you're using out-of-process session state storage.  In that case, without the interface, the system will still store the session data in the remote database, even when it hasn't changed (the system doesn't keep track of whether the session data was modified during the request).  When you use the IReadOnlySessionState interface, the write-back phase is skipped.

Comment: From where did you get that info ? can you refer to the link ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx

IRequiresSessionState is derived from System.Web.SessionState
using this interface we access session in Httphandler and Class file

If you need read-only access to the Session, implement the IReadOnlySessionState interface.

Comment: Yes, I know what `IRequiresSessionState` is used for, but why is `IReadOnlySessionState` exists? Why would I prefer to use it?

Comment: At PostMapRequestHandler the HttpModule swaps from the actual handler to a custom handler which implements IRequiresSessionState or IReadOnlySessionState so it can use seesion.
At PreRequestHandlerExecute you can access session and redirect if needed.
At PostAcquireRequestState you swap back to the orginal handler.