# How can I use a standard ASP.NET session object within ServiceStack service implementation

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I'm just getting started with ServiceStack and, as a test case, I am looking to rework an existing service which is built using standard ASP.Net handlers. I've managed to get it all working as I want it but have certain aspects which make use of the ASP.Net Session object.

I've tried adding IRequiresSessionState into the service interface:

```
public class SessionTestService : RestServiceBase<SessionTest>, IRequiresSessionState {
    public override object OnPost(SessionTest request) {
        // Here I want to use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session
    }
}
```

The trouble is I can't seem to get it to work as the Session object is always null.

I've done a lot of Googling and have puzzled over https://github.com/mythz/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.IntegrationTests/Services/Secure.cs and similar but I can't find any example code which does this (which surprises me). Can anyone explain why the above doesn't work and advise what I need to do to get it working?

**Note:** Ultimately I'll probably look to replace this with Redis or will try to remove any serverside session requirement, but I figured that I'd use the ASP.Net implementation for the time being, to get things working and to avoid reworking it more than is necessary at this point.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Using ServiceStack ISession**

ServiceStack has a new `ISession` interface backed by `ICacheClient` that lets you share  same `ISession` between MVC Controllers, ASP.NET base pages and ServiceStack's Web Services which share the same Cookie Id allowing you to freely share data between these web frameworks.

Note: ISession is a **clean implementation** that completely by-passes the existing ASP.NET session with ServiceStack's own components as described in [ServiceStack's MVC PowerPack](http://www.servicestack.net/mvc-powerpack/) and explained in detail in the [Sessions wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions).

To easily make use of ServiceStack's Session (Cache & JSON Serializer) have your Controllers inherit from [ServiceStackController](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3/Mvc/ServiceStackController.cs) (in MVC) or [PageBase](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.IntegrationTests/PageBase.cs) (in ASP.NET)

There is also new Authentication / Validation functionality added in ServiceStack which you can read about on the wiki:

- [Authentication and authorization](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization)
- [Validation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation)

**Using ASP.NET Session**

Essentially [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) is just a set of lightweight **IHttpHandler's** running on either an ASP.NET or HttpListener host. If hosted in IIS/ASP.NET (most common) it works like a normal ASP.NET request.

Nothing in ServiceStack accesses or affects the configured Caching and Session providers in the underlying ASP.NET application. If you want to enable it you would need to configure it as per normal in ASP.NET (i.e. outside of ServiceStack) see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Once configured you can access the ASP.NET session inside a ServiceStack web service via the singleton:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Or alternatively via the underlying ASP.NET HttpRequest with:

```
var req = (HttpRequest)base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().OriginalRequest;
var session = req.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session;
```

Although because of the mandatory reliance on XML config and [degraded performance by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629709/i-just-discovered-why-all-asp-net-websites-are-slow-and-i-am-trying-to-work-out), I prefer to shun the use of ASP.NET's Session, instead opting to use the cleaner [Cache Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) included with ServiceStack.

Basically the way Sessions work (ASP.NET included) is a cookie containing a **unique id** is added to the Response uniquely identifying the browser session. This **id** points to a matching Dictionary/Collection on the server which represents the browsers' Session.

The **IRequiresSession** interface you link to doesn't do anything by default, it simply is a way to signal to either a Custom Request Filter or base web service that this request needs to be authenticated (i.e. two places where you should put validation/authentication logic in ServiceStack).

Here's a [Basic Auth implementation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/RequestFiltersTests.cs#L91) that looks to see if a web service is Secure and if so make sure they have authenticated.

Here's [another authentication implementation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/AuthService.cs#L83) that instead validates all services marked with an **[Authenticate]** attribute, and [how to enable Authentication for your service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/ServiceInterface/UserProfileService.cs#L11) by adding the Attribute on your Request DTO.

#### New Authentication Model in ServiceStack

The above implementation is apart of the multi-auth provider model included in the next version of ServiceStack. Here's [the reference example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/App_Start/ServiceStackFramework.cs#L138) showing how to register and configure the new Auth model in your application.

#### Authentication Strategies

The new Auth model is entirely an opt-in convenience as you can simply not use it and implement similar behaviour yourself using **Request Filters** or in **base classes** (by overriding [OnBeforeExecute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/ServiceBase.cs#L134)). In fact the new Auth services are not actually built-into ServiceStack per-se. The entire implementation lives in the optional [ServiceStack.ServiceInterfaces project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface) and implemented using Custom Request Filters.

Here are different Authentication strategies I've used over the years:

- Mark services that need authentication with an **[Attribute]**. Likely the most idiomatic C# way, ideal when the **session-id** is passed via a Cookie.
- Especially outside of a Web Context, sometimes using a more explicit **IRequiresAuthentication** interface is better as it provides strong-typed access to the User and SessionId required for Authentication.
- You can just have a 1-liner to authenticate on each service that needs it - on an adhoc basis. A suitable approach when you have very few services requiring authentication.

Comment: Fantastic answer, I am very grateful for the detailed explanation, thank you.

Comment: In service stack current implementation, accessing the underlying ASP.NET HttpRequest with (((HttpRequest)base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().OriginalRequest).Session) does not work/compile.

Answer (score 19):

That's a great and comprehensive answer by @mythz. However, when trying to access the ASP.NET session by `HttpContext.Current.Session` within a ServiceStack web service, it always returns `null` for me. That's because none of the HttpHandlers within ServiceStack are adorned with the `IRequiresSessionState` interface, so the .NET Framework does not provide us with the session object.

To get around this, I've implemented two new classes, both of which use the decorator pattern to provide us with what we need.

Firstly, a new `IHttpHandler` which requires session state. It wraps the `IHttpHandler` provided by ServiceStack and passes calls through to it...

```
public class SessionHandlerDecorator : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState {
    private IHttpHandler Handler { get; set; }

    internal SessionHandlerDecorator(IHttpHandler handler) {
        this.Handler = handler;
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get { return Handler.IsReusable; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        Handler.ProcessRequest(context);
    }
}
```

Next, a new `IHttpHandlerFactory` which delegates the responsibility for generating the `IHttpHandler` to ServiceStack, before wrapping the returned handler in our new `SessionHandlerDecorator`...

```
public class SessionHttpHandlerFactory : IHttpHandlerFactory {
    private readonly static ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory factory = new ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory();

    public IHttpHandler GetHandler(HttpContext context, string requestType, string url, string pathTranslated) {
        var handler = factory.GetHandler(context, requestType, url, pathTranslated);
        return handler == null ? null : new SessionHandlerDecorator(handler);
    }

    public void ReleaseHandler(IHttpHandler handler) {
        factory.ReleaseHandler(handler);
    }

}
```

Then, it's just a matter of changing the `type` attributes in the handlers in Web.config to `SessionHttpHandlerFactory` instead of `ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack`, and your web services should now have the ASP.NET session avaialble to them.

Despite the above, I fully endorse the new `ISession` implementation provided by ServiceStack. However, in some cases, on a mature product, it just seems too big a job to replace all uses of the ASP.NET session with the new implementation, hence this workaround!

Comment: You're right...It is a big job. One thing you could consider for the future is creating wrappers around assets like Session and configuring them with a DI container. That'll make it much easier for you to change things in the future

Comment: A very good solution for intranet based websites, thanks Richard.

Comment: @Richard Fawcett This solution giving me error   "Could not load type 'SessionHttpHandlerFactory'"  i have followed all steps mentioned  , iam using ServiceStack version 4

Comment: Hey @amol ... SessionHttpHandlerFactory is one of the classes we write ourselves, so if it can't be found, this seems unlikely related to the version of ServiceStack you're using.
Ensure you have the fully namespaced class name to SessionHttpHandlerFactory in your Web.config.

Comment: @Richard Fawcett   when i use this solution i am able to access the the asp.net session in servicestack application  But in service stack application session is created at each inbound request with diffrent session id .                                                                                 My mvc.net application and servicestack spplication ( simple asp.net website) is deployed on different server.

Comment: i am using sessionState mode="SQLServer" with setting useHostingIdentity="false" timeout="20" cookieless="false" .  how to persist session for inbound request  ( from same session in requesting application)?

Comment: any idea about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917908/how-to-get-the-session-details-in-servicestack-application-from-sqlserver-using

Comment: Sharing session state between two different web applications is not something I've ever done, so don't think I can be of any use to you here I'm afraid @amol.

Comment: If you're getting a new session id with each request to the ServiceStack API, I'd guess you're not persisting and sending the session cookie with your API calls.

Comment: yes i am using SQL session mode for persisting the session. i am sending the session cookie with api calls. Please see update in following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917908/how-to-get-the-session-details-in-servicestack-application-from-sqlserver-using

Comment: A note for anyone else using this solution. IRequiresSessionState puts an exclusive lock on the current session, so no concurrent servicestack requests, as from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039014/irequiressessionstate-vs-ireadonlysessionstate. So implement IReadOnlySessionState  if you want to avoid this.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @Richard for your answer above. I am running a new version of service stack and they have removed the ServiceStackHttpFactory with HttpFactory. Instead of having

```
private readonly static ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory factory = new ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory();
```

You need to have

```
private static readonly HttpHandlerFactory Factory = new HttpHandlerFactory();
```

Here is updated code for this service

```
using ServiceStack;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace MaryKay.eCommerce.Mappers.AMR.Host
{
public class SessionHttpHandlerFactory : IHttpHandlerFactory
{
    private static readonly HttpHandlerFactory Factory = new HttpHandlerFactory();
    public IHttpHandler GetHandler(HttpContext context, string requestType, string url, string pathTranslated)
    {
        var handler = Factory.GetHandler(context, requestType, url, pathTranslated);
        return handler == null ? null : new SessionHandlerDecorator(handler);
    }

    public void ReleaseHandler(IHttpHandler handler)
    {
        Factory.ReleaseHandler(handler);
    }
}

public class SessionHandlerDecorator : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    private IHttpHandler Handler { get; set; }

    internal SessionHandlerDecorator(IHttpHandler handler)
    {
        Handler = handler;
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return Handler.IsReusable; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Handler.ProcessRequest(context);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of ServiceStack 4.5+ the HttpHandler can also support Async. Like so:

```
namespace FboOne.Services.Host
{
  public class SessionHttpHandlerFactory : IHttpHandlerFactory
  {
    private static readonly HttpHandlerFactory Factory = new HttpHandlerFactory();

    public IHttpHandler GetHandler(HttpContext context, string requestType, string url, string pathTranslated)
    {
      var handler = Factory.GetHandler(context, requestType, url, pathTranslated);
      return handler == null ? null : new SessionHandlerDecorator((IHttpAsyncHandler)handler);
    }

    public void ReleaseHandler(IHttpHandler handler)
    {
      Factory.ReleaseHandler(handler);
    }
  }

  public class SessionHandlerDecorator : IHttpAsyncHandler, IRequiresSessionState
  {
    private IHttpAsyncHandler Handler { get; set; }

    internal SessionHandlerDecorator(IHttpAsyncHandler handler)
    {
      Handler = handler;
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
      get { return Handler.IsReusable; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
      Handler.ProcessRequest(context);
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
      return Handler.BeginProcessRequest(context, cb, extraData);
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
      Handler.EndProcessRequest(result);
    }
  }
}
```