# Can I use ServiceStack's ISession in a ASP.NET hosted IHttpHandler and existing ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, servicestack, ihttphandler

I'm in the process of migrating my app over to ServiceStack, and have registered up the existing MVC3 Controllers using ServiceStackController, as outlined by [How can I use a standard ASP.NET session object within ServiceStack service implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339584/how-can-i-use-a-standard-asp-net-session-object-within-servicestack-service-impl)

I don't see where to find the PageBase class, referenced in the article, outside from the test project.  Is this something i need to copy/paste over into my solution?

I also have a few custom IHttpHandler (.ashx) pages, that I'm trying to get on the same ISession, but I don't see a base class for that called out in the referenced post.  Is this possible, or do I need to move these IHttpHandler's to ServiceStack services to be able to take advantage of ISession?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET [PageBase class is a T4 template](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/NuGet/ServiceStack.Host.AspNet/content/App_Start/PageBase.cs.pp) that gets added when you install the [ServiceStack.Host.AspNet](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Host.AspNet) NuGet package.

All of ServiceStack's Caching and Session support is completely independent of MVC controllers and ASP.NET base pages just comes from resolving the `ICacheClient` and `ISessionFactory` from ServiceStack's IOC.

If your MVC Controllers and ASP.NET base pages are auto-wired you can just declare them as public properties and they will get injected by [ServiceStack's IOC](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container) otherwise you can access ServiceStack's IOC directly with the singleton:

```
var cache = Endpoint.AppHost.TryResolve<ICacheClient>();
var typedSession = cache.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>(  //Uses Ext methods
    HttpContext.Current.Request.ToRequest(),  //ASP.NET HttpRequest singleton
    HttpContext.Current.Request.ToResponse()  //ASP.NET HttpResponse singleton
);
```

Accessing the session is all done the same way, here's the sample code from ServiceStack's [Service.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Service.cs) base class:

```
    private ICacheClient cache;
    public virtual ICacheClient Cache
    {
        get { return cache ?? (cache = TryResolve<ICacheClient>()); }
    }

    private ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public virtual ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get { return sessionFactory ?? (sessionFactory = TryResolve<ISessionFactory>()) ?? new SessionFactory(Cache); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dynamic Session Bag
    /// </summary>
    private ISession session;
    public virtual ISession Session
    {
        get
        {
            return session ?? (session = SessionFactory.GetOrCreateSession(Request, Response));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Typed UserSession
    /// </summary>
    private object userSession;
    protected virtual TUserSession SessionAs<TUserSession>()
    {
        return (TUserSession)(userSession ?? (userSession = Cache.SessionAs<TUserSession>(Request, Response)));
    }
```