# Pass Session information from one website

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, web-hosting

We have created a project using **asp.net 3tire architecture** (Farmer System web).  As the 2nd part of that project developed another website using **Asp.net MVC4**(Portal web). these projects are **hosted separately**. When the user login to the farmer system he can also use the portal.

when user navigate to the portal, i want to **pass the logging session**. please anyone tell me how do i do it?

Comment: You might want to look into [SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Help from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339584/how-can-i-use-a-standard-asp-net-session-object-within-servicestack-service-impl/8380292#8380292)

**Using ServiceStack ISession**

ServiceStack has a new `ISession` interface backed by `ICacheClient` that lets you share  same `ISession` between MVC Controllers, ASP.NET base pages and ServiceStack's Web Services which share the same Cookie Id allowing you to freely share data between these web frameworks.

Note: ISession is a **clean implementation** that completely by-passes the existing ASP.NET session with ServiceStack's own components as described in [ServiceStack's MVC PowerPack](http://www.servicestack.net/mvc-powerpack/) and explained in detail in the [Sessions wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions).

To easily make use of ServiceStack's Session (Cache & JSON Serializer) have your Controllers inherit from [ServiceStackController](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3/Mvc/ServiceStackController.cs) (in MVC) or [PageBase](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.IntegrationTests/PageBase.cs) (in ASP.NET)

There is also new Authentication / Validation functionality added in ServiceStack which you can read about on the wiki:

- [Authentication and authorization](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization)
- [Validation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation)

**Using ASP.NET Session**

Essentially [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) is just a set of lightweight **IHttpHandler's** running on either an ASP.NET or HttpListener host. If hosted in IIS/ASP.NET (most common) it works like a normal ASP.NET request.

Nothing in ServiceStack accesses or affects the configured Caching and Session providers in the underlying ASP.NET application. If you want to enable it you would need to configure it as per normal in ASP.NET (i.e. outside of ServiceStack) see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Once configured you can access the ASP.NET session inside a ServiceStack web service via the singleton:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Or alternatively via the underlying ASP.NET HttpRequest with:

```
var req = (HttpRequest)base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().OriginalRequest;
var session = req.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session;
```

Although because of the mandatory reliance on XML config and [degraded performance by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629709/i-just-discovered-why-all-asp-net-websites-are-slow-and-i-am-trying-to-work-out), I prefer to shun the use of ASP.NET's Session, instead opting to use the cleaner [Cache Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) included with ServiceStack.

Basically the way Sessions work (ASP.NET included) is a cookie containing a **unique id** is added to the Response uniquely identifying the browser session. This **id** points to a matching Dictionary/Collection on the server which represents the browsers' Session.

The **IRequiresSession** interface you link to doesn't do anything by default, it simply is a way to signal to either a Custom Request Filter or base web service that this request needs to be authenticated (i.e. two places where you should put validation/authentication logic in ServiceStack).

Here's a [Basic Auth implementation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/RequestFiltersTests.cs#L91) that looks to see if a web service is Secure and if so make sure they have authenticated.

Here's [another authentication implementation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/AuthService.cs#L83) that instead validates all services marked with an **[Authenticate]** attribute, and [how to enable Authentication for your service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/ServiceInterface/UserProfileService.cs#L11) by adding the Attribute on your Request DTO.

#### New Authentication Model in ServiceStack

The above implementation is apart of the multi-auth provider model included in the next version of ServiceStack. Here's [the reference example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/App_Start/ServiceStackFramework.cs#L138) showing how to register and configure the new Auth model in your application.

#### Authentication Strategies

The new Auth model is entirely an opt-in convenience as you can simply not use it and implement similar behaviour yourself using **Request Filters** or in **base classes** (by overriding [OnBeforeExecute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/ServiceBase.cs#L134)). In fact the new Auth services are not actually built-into ServiceStack per-se. The entire implementation lives in the optional [ServiceStack.ServiceInterfaces project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface) and implemented using Custom Request Filters.

Here are different Authentication strategies I've used over the years:

- Mark services that need authentication with an **[Attribute]**. Likely the most idiomatic C# way, ideal when the **session-id** is passed via a Cookie.
- Especially outside of a Web Context, sometimes using a more explicit **IRequiresAuthentication** interface is better as it provides strong-typed access to the User and SessionId required for Authentication.
- You can just have a 1-liner to authenticate on each service that needs it - on an adhoc basis. A suitable approach when you have very few services requiring authentication.