# ServiceStack - System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, servicestack, session-cookies, session-state

I have legacy .net mvc application integrated with ServiceStack APIs, I need to get/set Session values from ServiceStack APIs in order to communicate with legacy system to ensure proper working. I explored multiple option available in ServiceStack doc/other material but looks like nothing is working in my case.

enabled session feature:

```
Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature());
```

tried to use direct:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

alternate way:

```
var req = (HttpRequest)base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().OriginalRequest;
var session = req.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session;
```

but none of them seems working.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339584/how-can-i-use-a-standard-asp-net-session-object-within-servicestack-service-impl)

Answer (score 0):

[ServiceStack Sessions](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) is a completely independent implementation with no dependency or coupling to ASP.NET’s Sessions.

To enable access to ASP.NET’s sessions within ServiceStack requests you’ll need to decorate its `IHttpHandler` with the `IRequiresSessionState` interface as documented [Enable ASP.NET Sessions](https://docs.servicestack.net/servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework#enable-aspnet-sessions) docs.