# ASp.net State server dealing with IRequiresSessionState vs IReadOnlySessionState?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, session-state-server

MY friend asked here a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039014/irequiressessionstate-vs-ireadonlysessionstate)

And the one who answered him  - wrote something interesting ! ( without any proof , source).

> It makes a bigger difference when you're using out-of-process session
>   state storage. In that case, without the interface, the system will
>   still store the session data in the remote database, even when it
>   hasn't changed (the system doesn't keep track of whether the session
>   data was modified during the request). When you use the
>   IReadOnlySessionState interface, the write-back phase is skipped.

Where Does it say that IRequiresSessionState will write back the session ( even if hadent changed.) ?

any explanations will be gladly excepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't find formal documentation to this effect, but firing up dotPeek (or some other disassembler) and having a look around `System.Web` successively reveals that:

- When `HttpContext.Handler` is `set`, if the handler implements `IRequiresSessionState`, `HttpContext._requiresSessionStateFromHandler` is set `true`;
- this latter private member informs the `get`ter for `HttpContext.RequiresSessionState`;
- `SessionStateModule` (which I am gong to guess is always in the module pipeline), in its `EndRequest` handler, checks `HttpContext.RequiresSessionState`, and if it's `true`, talks to the session state provider to save state.