# delay between PostMapRequestHandler Event and AcquireRequestState Event

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm facing a strange delay between the subject events (more or less 500ms each call).

I placed logs and profiling in the handlers in **Global.asax** `Application_PostMapRequestHandler()` and `Application_AcquireRequestState()` and found such issue.

What's the cause of this slowness?

Comment: Strange, take a look here, both methods are called one after the other in sequence. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/05/27/asp-net-application-life-cycle.aspx

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I'm so puzzled!! I cannot figure out what's going to be done between these two consecutive phases... Perhaps some locking activities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because if Session State is enabled for a controller - then only one request will execute at a time for each session.

More information is available in the following answer - see the second answer.

[IRequiresSessionState vs IReadOnlySessionState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039014/irequiressessionstate-vs-ireadonlysessionstate)