# Getting the `HttpContext` from a generic handler with an `HttpModule`

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule, asp.net-4.5

I am working on an `HttpModule` class for collecting performance and run time data of `ASP.Net` applications.

I've figured out how to access the `Session` for information on `ASPX` files and classes implementing `IHttpHandler` (such as custom web resources or `axd` files), but I can't find a way to access the instance of `HttpContext` that is passed into `ProcessRequest()` on a generic handler (`ASHX` file).

`Application.Session` throws an `HttpException`

> (Session state is not available in this context)

and the `HttpContext.Current.Session == null`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you add a new Generic Handler to your project, it shoudl look like this

```
public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }
```

Where `context` is passed as the HttpContext you can use.

And if you need to read a Session you need to add `IReadOnlySessionState` or `IRequiresSessionState` (for difference [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039014/irequiressessionstate-vs-ireadonlysessionstate))

```
using System.Web.SessionState;

public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question directly, but it's useful in that it challenges an assumption I had about passed in HttpContext passed in. Since my HttpModule has to to work with ASP.Net applications that we didn't write, and thus have no control over whether or not generic handlers have access to Session state and I need to account for that. Thanks!