# Writing to a read only session in MVC 3+

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, session-state

I've come across a curious behaviour of ASP sessions. You can force a controller to be outside of the user's session - I want to be able to do this so that multiple requests can execute at the same time and using a session causes them to execute consecutively.

Disabling session state works as expected:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Test() 
    {
        // Access to the session should be denied
        object test = Session["test"];
        return Content(test);
    }
}
```

Going to *~/Sample/Test* will throw a `System.Web.HttpException`, as expected. 
However, read-only sessions appear to behave a little strangely:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Test() 
    {
        // Read from the session should be fine
        object test = Session["test"];
        return Content(test);
    }

    public ActionResult SetTest(string value) 
    {
        // Write to the session should fail 
        Session["test"] = value;

        // Read it back from the session
        object test = Session["test"];
        return Content(test);
    }
}
```

So now I expect *~/Sample/Test* to work, and it does. The odd bit is that the set does too: I go to *~/Sample/SetTest?value=foo* and it doesn't throw an exception, in fact it returns "foo". If I call  *~/Sample/SetTest?value=bar* and then *~/Sample/Test* I get "bar", indicating that the session has been written to.

So in a `SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly` I have successfully written to the session and read my value back.

I think this could be due to one of three things:

- In MVC 3 `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]` is broken/ignored.
- The `[SessionState]` is overridden when the session is written to and becomes writeable.
- The `SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly` actually indicates some kind of dirty/optimistic access.

Can anyone confirm?

I suspect the last one is true, based off the [custom session provider documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx) - if it is then how does the implementation work? Does writing to a 'read only' session risk concurrency errors (i.e. last write wins) or does it risk corrupt sessions and breaking exceptions?

**Update**

It looks like this is by design (from [Microsoft's docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase.aspx)):

> Note that even if the EnableSessionState attribute is marked as
>   ReadOnly, other ASP.NET pages in the same application might be able to
>   write to the session store, so a request for read-only session data
>   from the store might still end up waiting for locked data to be freed.

It looks like the second option above is what it actually does - the session is locked and the mode changed to writable.

Answer (score 13):

~/Sample/SetTest?value=foo

Yes it won't throw any error, but it also didn't persist the session at the end of the request.  By design any thing that you write to session gets updated (only if the session is writable) at the very end of the request life-cycle.

In my test ~/Sample/Test returns nothing.

I think they should have failed fast here when the session is readonly.

By the way your sample need to be rewritten

```
string test = (string)this.Session["test"];
```

Comment: Hmm, the sample here is simplified code for what I'm doing, but I am getting the session written to - calling _~/Sample/SetTest?value=foo_ and then _~/Sample/Test_ is returning "foo" for me. Really it should error, and if not it should just fail to save the session, but it's definitely saving for me.

Comment: You're right, my sample in the question does fail to write to the session, as expected. Question is why is my app still able to write to it? I'll find out what's different and update the question...

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer above, they are not failing fast when the session is read-only and when you are updating it. Framework is simply ignoring the session update at the end of the request.  Meanwhile they allow you to modify the session structure anyway you like it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I expect it to do and what it actually does in a fresh dummy project. However in the actual app I set the controller to be read-only and it successfully saves changes to the session across requests. So there's something missing from my question - I'm going to have to play around with the dummy project to see if I can reproduce this.

Comment: Problem found, of a sort - turns out that ASP overrides `SessionStateBehavior` from read only in certain circumstances. Most writes will just silently fail, but actions in global.ascx seem to (sometimes) force it back to write, annoyingly locking the session at an unpredictable point in the page lifecycle. I've decided to drop ASP sessions entirely - what I need is dirty read and last write wins, and it can't support that at all.

Comment: The weird thing is here I can write to the session on a readonly status, and it actually writes. And then I can read it in another controller method (also readonly) and its there. Both are non-blocking and have a 5 second sleep. Yet if I remove the attribute, both block.

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT: I think you have good timings. However, MS cannot determine these timings and obviously blocked things.