# ASP.NET application throws System.NullReferenceException from Session.Remove implementation

Tags: asp.net, session, nullreferenceexception

We are getting random System.NullReferenceException in our ASP.NET web application. 
We are using inproc session state.
Stacktrace:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseRemove(String name)
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Remove(String name)
at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer.Remove(String name)
at System.Web.UI.SessionPageStatePersister.Save()
at System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

The problem seems to come from Page.PageStatePersister property which we have overriden like this.

```
protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister {
  get {
    return new SessionPageStatePersister(Page); 
  }
}
```

Reflector showed that SessionPageStatePersister internally calls Session.Remove.

We are getting similar random NullReferenceException while calling Session.Remove directly on Page.
Relevant stacktrace:

```
---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseRemove(String name)
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Remove(String name)
at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer.Remove(String name)
at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.Remove(String name)
at PERH.WebFramework.Bases.PageBase.OnPreInit(EventArgs e) in
```

Any idea, what might cause those exceptions?

Environment:

IIS6, Windows Server 2003 64-bit, .net Framework 3.5

Comment: I'm also getting a NullReferenceException from NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseRemove(string), which seems to occur when the website is under heavy load.  This implies some sort of race condition, however looking at the code for that method, there are only 3 variables being used in a way that could trigger a NullReferenceException, and I can't see any way any of those variables could ever be null, so it's a bit of a mystery to me.

Comment: Any findings on this issue, we are facing the same

Comment: did you get solution? please help me if you get solution

Answer (score 2):

The issue may occur when the requests made by the same user (from the same session ID) are processed concurrently.

This is because `System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection` doesn't check the entry to be null when removing it.

In the `System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Remove(string name)` method the lock is set on the private collection *`_serializedItems`* so that *Remove* operation is thread safe. Yet this private collection doesn't get locked during *Add* operations. Considering that *`_serializedItems`* behaves as a resizing array (when entries count is >= 1/2 of its capacity the capacity is doubled and new entries are filled with nulls) concurrent addition may result into situations when null values remain in the middle of the collection.
The entries only get removed from [0; entries count] range of the `_serializedItems` collection. When removing the entry its `Key` property gets accessed without null checking. Thus if **null** entry form the middle of the collection is removed the `NullReferenceException` gets cast.

By default all requests with same session ID are processed sequentially unless `System.Web.Configuration.PagesSection.EnableSessionState` is explicitly set to `ReadOnly`.
In this case any operation that involves adding values into `System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState` (which internally uses `System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer` which in turn internally uses `System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection`) should be properly locked to assure thread safety.

Comment: I have the same issue but can't find the solution I'm using https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/session-state-behavior-per-action-in-Asp-Net-mvc/ please help me