# Session.Keys System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.KeysCollection.Get Exception

Tags: session, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

Here is some visual studio immediate window debugging:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys[6]
"Persist_ResetOrgStructureGuid"

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys[7]
'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys[7]' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2147467261
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    Source: "System"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.KeysCollection.Get(Int32 index)\r\n   at System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.KeysCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)"
    TargetSite: {System.String Get(Int32)}

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys[8]
"StructureSearchFilter_AllOrganisationStructures"
```

How is it possible that the key (a string) at index 7 throws a null reference exception?

I used dotPeek to have a look at what System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.KeysCollection.Get does:

```
/// <summary>Gets the key at the specified index of the collection.</summary>
/// <returns>A <see cref="T:System.String" /> that contains the key at the specified index of the collection.</returns>
/// <param name="index">The zero-based index of the key to get from the collection. </param>
/// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
/// <paramref name="index" /> is outside the valid range of indexes for the collection. </exception>
public virtual string Get(int index)
{
    return this._coll.BaseGetKey(index);
}
```

Surely if **this** or **_coll** was null though it would throw the exception for any index, which it doesn't.

I tried adding a null session key in an attempt to reproduce the problem, which does not throw an exception:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(null, null)
Expression has been evaluated and has no value

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[10]
null
```

I understand what the exception means, but I am asking how it is possible that a session **key** becomes a null reference when it is just a string in a collection. Surely if it is removed then it shouldn't be in the Keys collection at all? (Not that I removed it anyway).

Edit:
Almost 2 years later and I'm still having the issue. I've found a way to reproduce it though:

```
Task task = new Task(delegate ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        Session.Add("test", "test");
});

Task task2 = new Task(delegate ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        Session.Remove("test");
});

task.Start();
task2.Start();
```

The above will throw an object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

Stack:

```
at System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseRemove(String name)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Remove(String name)
   at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer.Remove(String name)
   at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.Remove(String name)
```

These posts might be related:
https://forums.asp.net/t/1872972.aspx?Session+exception+terminates+application+pool

[ASP.NET application throws System.NullReferenceException from Session.Remove implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249269/asp-net-application-throws-system-nullreferenceexception-from-session-remove-imp)